# Why does the memory mapped file ever need to be flushed when access is RDWR?

Tags: go, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I was reading through one of golang's implementation of memory mapped files, https://github.com/edsrzf/mmap-go/. First he describes the several access modes:

```
// RDONLY maps the memory read-only.
// Attempts to write to the MMap object will result in undefined behavior.
RDONLY = 0
// RDWR maps the memory as read-write. Writes to the MMap object will update the
// underlying file.
RDWR = 1 << iota
// COPY maps the memory as copy-on-write. Writes to the MMap object will affect
// memory, but the underlying file will remain unchanged.
COPY
```

But in gommap test file I see this:

```
func TestReadWrite(t *testing.T) {
  mmap, err := Map(f, RDWR, 0)
  ... omitted for brevity...
  mmap[9] = 'X'
  mmap.Flush()
```

So why does he need to call Flush to make sure the contents are written to the file if the access mode is RDWR?

Or is the OS managing this so it only writes when it thinks it should?

If the last option, could you please explain it in a little more detail - what i read is that when the OS is low in memory it writes to the file and frees up memory. Is this correct and does it apply only to RDWR or only to COPY?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The program maps a region of memory using `mmap`.  It then modifies the mapped region.  The system isn't required to write those modifications back to the underlying file immediately, so a `read` call on that file (in `ioutil.ReadAll`) could return the prior contents of the file.

The system **will** write the changes to the file at some point after you make the changes.
It is **allowed** to write the changes to the file any time after the changes are made, but by default makes no guarantees about when it writes those changes.  All you know is that (unless the system crashes), the changes will be written at some point in the future.

If you need to guarantee that the changes have been written to the file at some point in time, then you must call `msync`.

The `mmap.Flush` function calls `msync` with the `MS_SYNC` flag.  When that system call returns, the system has written the modifications to the underlying file, so that any subsequent call to `read` will read the modified file.

The `COPY` option sets the mapping to `MAP_PRIVATE`, so your changes will **never** be written back to the file, even if you using `msync` (via the `Flush` function).

Read the POSIX documentation about [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mmap.html) and [`msync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/msync.html) for full details.

Comment: Thanks, so the RDWR flag does not mean it will be written immediately.  Does the system only write to the file upon calls to mysync or munmap? "RDWR - Writes to the MMap object will update the underlying file." seems to imply that sometime in the future those changes will be written even if the user does not call msync or munmap.. Basically could you comment on the last 2 paragraphs in the question? Thanks!

Comment: @sofia: Writes are generally "lazy", although practically they are "immediate" most of the time because of unified virtual memory systems (this is not something that is _guaranteed_, though). Even when the data is not written to disk, a subsequent read operation will _usually_ still pull the correct data from the buffer cache anyway -- however, you don't know, there's no guarantee.  A program that needs this guarantee and needs to be portable (i.e. not rely on a system's implementation) must flush to be sure.

Comment: if I am writing 100 bytes at a time upto 1KB in a loop can it get flushed in the midway? or is there any guarantee that it will wait for all 1KB to complete and eventually it will write to disk at some point later?

Comment: The system can flush your writes midway.